# Getting AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sourceCrs' from TIN Interpolation in QGIS?

Tags: qgis-3, interpolation, tin, attributeerror

I am trying to use the TIN interpolation to interpolate conductivities between a vector layer in QGIS 3.4. and I always get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\TinInterpolation.py", line 171, in processAlgorithm
crs = layer.sourceCrs()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sourceCrs'
```

[image]

Does anyone have encountered this error already? I didn't find anything about it. The CRS is homogeneous in all my layers.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.